# TOC gets mixed with the next element

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm facing this problem since this morning and I don't know how to fix it:

[image]

As you can see I've highlighted the issue and this is my code :

```
\documentclass{stage_iut_mp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\newcommand\tab[1][1.25cm]{\hspace*{#1}}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

 \let\origaddvspace\addvspace
 \renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{}

\addto{\captionsfrench}{% Making babel aware of special titles
  \renewcommand{\mtctitle}{Plan}
}

\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
\vspace*{\fill}
{\centering Cette page a été laissée volontairement libre.\par}
\vspace{\fill}}

\begin{document}

\blankpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}

\section*{\begin{center}
Dédicaces
\end{center} }

\paragraph{}
\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}

\section*{\begin{center}
Remerciements
\end{center} }

\paragraph{}
\newpage
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}} 

\newpage
\listoffigures
\vspace{-2em}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\listoftables
 \renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{\origaddvspace{#1}}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage
\section*{\begin{center}
Introduction Générale
\end{center} }
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Introduction Générale}}

\chapter{Étude expérimentale et tests }
\minitoc
\section{Introduction}
\paragraph{}
\section{ Conclusion}
\paragraph{}

\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Conclusion Générale}}
\chapter*{\begin{center}
Conclusion Générale
\end{center} }


\end{document}
```

and this is `stage_iut_mp` class :

```
\ProvidesFile{stage_iut_mp.cls}
\ProvidesClass{stage_iut_mp}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} % pour quelques symboles math�matiques comme <ou=
\usepackage[amssymb,cdot]{SIunits}
\usepackage{mathcomp} % pour avoir le mu droit  $\tcmu$
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{palatino}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % espace entre les lignes
\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % permet de num�roter 4 niveaux
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    % et en affiche 2 dans la toc   
\def\chapitre#1{\chapter{#1}\newpage}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection})}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection})} 
\newcommand\remerciements{\chapter*{Remerciements}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Remerciements}}
\newcommand\introduction{\chapter*{Introduction}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}}  
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark} 
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{\setlength{0.7cm}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{\setlength{0.7cm}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{\setlength{0.7cm}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{\setlength{0.7cm}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\if@mainmatter\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \fi\ #1}%
{\if@mainmatter\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \fi\ #1}}
```

Comment: complete MWE please.

Comment: i've made edits on my post

Comment: What document class is `stage_iut_mp`? My LaTeX distribution doesn't have it. The kind of thing you're seeing depends a lot on the document class. Try with `book` and if the error disappears, then post a link to this `stage_iut_mp` so we can see what's going on.

Comment: the `stage_iut_mp` is a cutomized class file i've add it to my post. i've tried with `book` but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. On line 24 of your code excerpt you have:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
```

Change this to:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ Added \endgraf here to break the line
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage\endgraf}% <filler-page-format>
```

I couldn't test it though, but apparently the section ToC line is on top of the chapter ToC line. The cause apparently is the lack of a line break there. If it doesn't work I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @ElarbiMohamedAymen Just for clarification: `\endgraf` is basically the same as `\par` or a blank line, with the difference that sometimes TeX does not allow `\par` (or a blank line) in the argument of a macro, whereas `\endgraf` is allowed.

Comment: That's good to know really i did not knew that.